# Lex and Yacc to make compiler?

Tags: yacc, lex

I am starting a toy compiler, and I am making the simplest thing I can imagine, but it won't work.

Lex compiles, and Yacc compiles, and they link together, but the outputted program does not do what I expected.

Lex:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
void yyerror(char *);
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%


a                       { 
                            yylval = atoi(yytext);
                            return AAA;
                        }
.                       yyerror("invalid character");

%%
int yywrap(void) {
 return 1;
}
```

Yacc:

```
%{
    void yyerror(char *);
    int yylex(void);
    int sym[26];
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%token AAA

%%
daaaa:
AAA             {printf("%d\n", $1);}

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
 fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
 yyparse();
 return 0;
}
```

The program I am trying to compile with this compiler is a file containing: `a`. that's it.

I don't know what's happened!

Clarification: What I expected the compiled compiler to do was to accept a file into it, process the file, and spit out a compiled version of that file.

Comment: It would help if you revealed your expectations and how they are unfulfilled by your program.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of trying to convert the letter "a"  to an integer with `atoi`?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 yylval returns an int by default, and by subtracting var by "a" gives the input a surefire way to get 26 different yylval values without remembering previous inputs.

Comment: @Stegosaurus `atoi("a")` returns zero, and so does `atoi("b")`. There is no 'subtracting var by "a"' here, and nothing surefire about this bug in your code.

Comment: When I compile the code and run it (`./gl <<< 'a'` in Bash), it prints 0 and a couple of newlines.  I'm not sure what you expected it to print.  It will only read from standard input unless you take steps to organize it differently (by setting `yyin` to point to a different file stream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you explain, maybe in an answer, exactly what you did, and how it worked, because as far as I can tell, and as far as I have tested the question, it shouldn't work as you say.

I took your code verbatim, creating files `grammar.y` and `lexer.l`.  I then compiled the code.  I'm working on Mac OS X 10.11.4, using GCC 6.1.0, Bison 2.3 (disguised as `yacc`) and Flex 2.5.35 (disguised as `lex`).

```
$ yacc -d grammar.y
$ lex lexer.l
$ gcc -o gl y.tab.c lex.yy.c
$ ./gl <<< 'a'
0

$
```

I subsequently made two changes.  In `grammar.y`, I changed `main()` to:

```
int main(void) {
 #if YYDEBUG
 yydebug = 1;
 #endif
 yyparse();
 return 0;
}
```

and in `lexer.l`, I changed the default character rule to:

```
\n|.                    yyerror("invalid character");
```

(The `.` doesn't match newline, so the newline after the `a` in the input was echoed by default in the original output.)

With a similar compilation, the output becomes:

```
$ ./gl <<< 'a'
0
invalid character
$
```

With the compilation specifying `-DYYDEBUG` too:

```
$ gcc -DYYDEBUG -o gl lex.yy.c y.tab.c
$
```

the output includes useful debugging information:

```
$ ./gl <<< 'a'
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token AAA ()
Shifting token AAA ()
Entering state 1
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 12):
   $1 = token AAA ()
0
-> $$ = nterm daaaa ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Reading a token: invalid character
Now at end of input.
Stack now 0 2
Cleanup: popping nterm daaaa ()
$ ./gl <<< 'aa'
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token AAA ()
Shifting token AAA ()
Entering state 1
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 12):
   $1 = token AAA ()
0
-> $$ = nterm daaaa ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Reading a token: Next token is token AAA ()
syntax error
Error: popping nterm daaaa ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token AAA ()
Stack now 0
$
```

The second `a` in the input correctly triggers a syntax error (it isn't allowed by the grammar).  Other characters are permitted, generate a 'invalid character' message, and are otherwise ignored (so `./gl <<< 'abc'` generates 3 invalid character messages, one for the `b`, one for the `c`, and one for the newline).

Changing the assignment to `yylval` in `lexer.l` to:

```
yylval = 'a'; // atoi(yytext);
```

changes the number printed from 0 to 97, which is the character code for `'a'` in ASCII, ISO 8859-1, Unicode, etc.

I've been using a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) as the source of data.  It would be equally feasible to have used a file as the input:

```
$ echo a > program
$ cat program
a
$ ./gl < a
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token AAA ()
Shifting token AAA ()
Entering state 1
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 12):
   $1 = token AAA ()
97
-> $$ = nterm daaaa ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Reading a token: invalid character
Now at end of input.
Stack now 0 2
Cleanup: popping nterm daaaa ()
$
```

If you want to read files specified by name on the command line, you have to write more code in `main()` to process those files.

Answer (score 2):

The program does not accept a file because it was not told to.

In the Yacc program,
`extern FILE *yyin;` must be added in the **definitions** section.

I believe that's it.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know why I expected the compiler to do the unreasonable and unwritten magic I expected it to do!

Comment: I don't think the suggestion to add `extern FILE *yyin;` is particularly relevant.  There's nothing visible that references it; when I test, it works for me without it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you explain, maybe in an answer, exactly what you did, and how it worked, because as far as I can tell, and as far as I have tested the question, it shouldn't work as you say.